# Yasson not converting subclasses properly

Tags: java, json, jsonb, payara-micro, yasson

I am building an application for payara-micro. I need to convert a Json string to an object that extends a super class. The problem that I have is that both the parent and the child's fields are not populated and the instance created is not of type sub-class:

E.g. `Person` has a list of `Vehicle` (subtypes: `Bike`, `Bus`,...)

```
  {
      name: "John",
      vehicles: [
          {
              type: "bike",
              doors: 5
          }
      ]
  }
```

The resulting object of this json will be a `Person` object with `name` populated, and a list of `Vehicle` with  one element but the type of that element will be `Vehicle` and no fields in `Vehicle` will have a value.

```
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
Person person = jsonb.fromJson(jsonString, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the functionality you're looking for is not part of Yasson (nor JSON-B). The specification doesn't explicitly mention this, but the [User Guide on Serializers/Deserializers](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/docs/user-guide.html#serializers-deserializers) hints at it (emphasis mine):

> Let’s take a look at the sample. Imagine that we would like to serialize and deserialize a list of pet carriers. A carried pet defined by an abstract class Animal. It can be any of its subclasses. We would like to properly serialize and deserialize it. **In order to do it we need to preserve a type information in JSON document and use it on deserialization. It can be done using custom serializer/deserializer pair.**

The example contains a custom serializer/deserializer, which should get you the desired result, but you will have to implement this custom serializer/deserializer yourself.